# Getting the word 'Array' inserted when passing an array in php using JSON

Tags: php, sql, json

I have created a webpage which includes the following php code...

```
$brandArray = JSON_decode(DatabaseInterface::getBrands(), true);
sort($brandArray);
for ($loop=0; $loop < sizeof($brandArray); $loop++) {
    echo "<option>$brandArray[$loop]</option>";
}
```

the relevant bits of the function DatabaseInterface::getBrands are here...

```
$query = "SELECT psBrandName from brands";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query. ".mysqli_error($con));

$resultArray[] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    extract($row);
    $resultArray[] = $psBrandName;

}

return json_Encode($resultArray);
```

Everything is working fine, except, bizarrely, when I look at the outputs on the webpage, the first item in the list is the word 'Array' (which isnt in the database. Any ideas?

Comment: why are you are `json_encode`(-ing) this stuff?

Comment: because I call the same fucntion with javascript in other places so needed the output to be a universal format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$resultArray[] = array()` means to push an empty array onto the `$resultArray` array. Remove the square brackets.